# Why does my server adds a mystery style to index.html?

Tags: html, css, express, server, static-content

I set up a basic node, express, react app and express is serving static content including my css. When I view source I noticed that index.html has this added in the head tag:

```html
<style type="text/css">* {}</style>
```

It's defiantly not in the actual file. Where did this come from?

Also, I don't see my actual css rendering on the page. However I do see the css file is loading in chrome network tab. I also see bootstrap style fine and they are served the same way. What's going on here?

My server:

```js
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');
    
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors());

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

http.createServer(app).listen(8080), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 8080');
});
```

This is what I have in my css

```css
body{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: You are asking why server add things but no informations about the server itself...

Comment: What does `index.html` look like? Also, in order to discount any browser plugins injecting the CSS, have you tried loading the page in incognito/private with all extensions disabled?

Comment: Usually servers don't add additional data unless specified. That line should have for a different reason. It'll be better if you can share your `index.html` and your css.

Comment: @godfrzero it's gone in incognito mode. Wow I didn't realized I have an extension adding that.

Comment: @AnnaGarcia Adblockers tend to inject CSS like this, as do a lot of other extensions.

Comment: @godfrzero good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was from @godfrzero - a chrome extension was causing the mystery style.